# remove string that is before * and get your sorted code and its value as an JSON object

Tags: python, string

In the below String, I need to get sorted Code and its value  `5q8-34fc3-00fd34 as` an Object in python

> "IF NONE OF ABOVE BOXES ARE TICKED THE LOCAL CURRENCY WILL BE APPLIED 3. Your details *Your Sorted Code: 5q8-34fc3-00fd34"

Comment: use a regex: `Sorted Code.*`

Answer (score 0):

> *I need to get sorted Code and its value 5q8-34fc3-00fd34 as an Object
>   in python*

---

[Everything in python is an object.](https://medium.com/meatandmachines/things-i-learned-about-objects-in-python-3-11aeae99332c)
To match the desired code, you can use a [regex](https://pythonprogramming.net/regular-expressions-regex-tutorial-python-3/) (`import re`):

```
import re
text = """
IF NONE OF ABOVE BOXES ARE TICKED THE LOCAL CURRENCY WILL BE APPLIED 3. Your details *Your Sorted Code: 5q8-34fc3-00fd34
"""
m = re.findall(r"Code: ([^\s]+)$", text)
if m:
    code = m[0]
    print(code)
    # 5q8-34fc3-00fd34
```

---

Notes:

1. [Python Demo](https://ideone.com/bLVw8C)
2. [Regex Demo & Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/4xNh8g/1)